# Link label is cut off at the buttom c#

Tags: c#, winforms, linklabel

In my C# winform application I have a link label.
when the text in the link label is localize to chinese the text is cut off at the buttom by the line of the link label.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

East Asian machines tend to run with a larger system font size to make characters more legible.  The setting of Form.AutoScaleMode matters, so does the Form's Font vs the control's Font.  Ensure that your form scales properly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the font you are using for the link label. Try changing the font or setting different size.

I don't think you've posted enough information. You could post a screenshot.